# I am sad about [api]

Tags: discussion, tags

We have 87 questions tagged [api](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api):

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api

Checking a portion of them reveals that these questions are asking for either:

- a [library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library) to embed in their application
- [web-services](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-services) to call from their app
- a client app that is compatible with a particular existing API

Are you happy with this tag? Could we improve it? Is it redundant?

Comment: Be happy Nicolas!  You're awesome! :-)

Comment: We also have the tag [tag:web-apis].

Comment: Well, can we count this a consense? IMHO yes, so you could go ahead :)

Answer (score 7):

I think this tag is redundant and should be removed. We should encourage askers to use more meaningful tags:

- a library to embed in their application: Tag as [library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library)
- a web service to call from their app: Tag as [web-services](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-services)
- a client app that is compatible with a particular existing API: Tag as the product providing that API, for instance [ebay](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebay) or [outlook](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook).

Message suggestion by Thomas:

> "You're trying to tag as [api]. You're probably better with [library] or [web-services]. If it's a product specific API, tag it with the product name."

Comment: I agree with you.  I'm a little concerned about people understanding the difference between `web-app` and `web-services`, and removing `api` might cause some erroneous tagging.  Regardless, I think this is minimal and the *likely* benefits will outweigh any *possible* costs.

Comment: Thinking a bit aloud here: Given that `api` is a popular tag, and cannot be "synonymed" (I think I just invented a word) with multiple other tags (right?), it might be reappear quickly as people try to use it.  Maybe you can add to your answer how to deal with this.  BTW, I'm not a big fan of tags that say "don't use this tag"... LOL.

Comment: I have to agree with rockpaperlizard: people start using the term *api* more and more for any kind of interface or library. I doubt we can 'enforce' proper use. If we undertake any tag cleanup (and maybe even if we don't) the usage of these terms and tags needs a good meta post.

Comment: Personally, when looking for an API I wouldn't have thought of googling for "web services". Also, it seems there are more answers in [tag:api] than in [tag:web-services]. Removing [tag:api] in favor of more specialized tags such as [tag:web-apis] could work, but I have also noticed that [tag:web-apis] has no tag wiki definition and appears to be used for two different purposes: people looking for web API's they can call and people looking for code to implement their own web API.

Comment: As for [tag:web-services], it seems that many (most?) questions are not using the tag to mean machine-to-machine communication.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: we don't need a "don't use this" description. We need a "You're trying to tag as [api]. You're probably better with [library] or [web-services]. If it's a product specific API, tag it with the product name." description